# In community of 400 adults, 300 bike or swim or do both,. 160 swim and 120 swim and bike.

Tags: probability

ppose that in a community of 400 adults, 300 bike or swim or do both,. 160 swim and 120 swim and bike. What is the probability that an adult selected at random from this community bikes?

I got 140/400 because 160 +120+20=300

Therefore 20 must bike and not swim.
It is also given that 120 swim and bike.

Therefore 140/400 bike.

Comment: You are correct.  just simplify.  7/20

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because it says the 300 are people who bike or swim or do both, and the 160 doesn't say swim or do both. It must be assumed those people swim only, otherwise the phrasing is inconsistent. So with 400, minus 160 who swim only, minus 100 who do nothing, that leaves 140 who either bike only or swim and bike.

Comment: I am sure, that's why I wrote something. Because the 300 group is described as bike or swim or both, the 160 must be swim only, since it wasn't described as "or both" as the 300 group was. Otherwise the text is written inconsistently and can't be trusted. But I look forward to a response from Bob on this.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven You are wrong. Here missed is fact, that one person can be in "120" and in "160". There is no "swim only". Simple example: Group $\{ a, b, c\}$ bike or swim. $a, b$ - swim. $b, c$ - bike. You know $a, b$ swim and only $b$ bike and swim. However, you can conclude that only $c$ only bike. And $b$ and $c$ bike.

Comment: @JoeM I see your point. However, I think here "or do both" is to draw attention to fact, that one person can do both. However, writing that every time is absolutely pointless. Same as writing $\in \mathbb{R}$, if it is obvious that we talk about real numbers. Let's not be so great purists.

Comment: I just read it wrong.  It is clearly 260.  My quick Venn Diagram was mislabeled.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$N(S\cup B)=N(S)+N(B)-N(S\cap B)\implies 300=160+N(B)-120\implies N(B)=260$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
A - \texttt{Bike}\\
B - \texttt{Swim}\\
C - \texttt{Do nothing}\\
$$
Then
$$
|\Omega| = |A \cup B \cup C| = 400\\
|A \cup B| = 300\\
|B| = 160\\
|A \cap B| = 120\\
$$
You are looking for $\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$.

**Hint:** Use [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: That would give A= 300-160+120 =260?? If I rearranged the formula.

Comment: That's right @Bob. $260/400$ is the answer